# Convert vector to OpenCV Matd1d in c++

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, vector

I have a variable `M` that is a `cv::Mat1d` matrix. It is made like this:

```
cv::Mat1d<double> M;
```

It is populated with a bunch of values in some other code that is probably not necessary and it looks like this when I print it:

```
[-0.9344576352096885;
 -0.9344576352096885;
 -0.5766199600499906;
 0.2846686026510846;
 0.9589011777015718;
 0.9285453673591227;
 0.3137239980297359;
 -0.2302718892981206;
 -0.2921750731112262;
 -0.2206633656711884;
 -0.2175072323850435;
 -0.1725991485554647;
 -0.2140556050785325;
 -0.4148403958730175;
 -0.4036417215304363;
 -0.06016889338878993;
 0.3028103268622913;
 0.4454375499811856;
 0.3803583582813156;
 0.3188387192279333;
 0.3914868895364941;
 0.4488724871465618;
 0.2694705005556897;
 -0.05248136866304744;
 -0.2971598882254832;
 -0.3545797186279719;
 -0.2294426230118397;
 -0.1673776410980104;
 -0.2768386357175945;
 -0.3276029287776189;
 -0.2361695287135101;
 -0.06139424097086685;
 0.1621769468562924;
 0.3275221571852822;
 0.3153071221383847;
 0.1341365194415481;
 -0.04596232030582767;
 -0.08961855126383761;
 -0.02999823421387905;
 -0.03225119207066054]
```

It is size `[1 x 40]`.

I had to convert `M` to a vector `X` to do some calculations on it. I converted it like this:

```
vector<ld> X;
X.push_back(M.at<double>(0, 0));
for (int i = 1; i < M.rows; i++) {
    X.push_back(M.at<double>(i, 0));
    }
```

Now when I print it (After the calculations I did which are irrelevant), it looks like this:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 -1 -1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
```

and is size `40`.

How do I convert `X` back to a [1x40] `cv::Mat1d` so that it is the same type as `M`?

Note: If my question/syntax/anything else is appalling, my apologies. I am just now leaving the relative safety of python for c++...

#### Edit

I think I solved it. In case anyone is curious OR if my solution needs correcting, here it is:

```
 Mat1d test;
    for (int i = 0; i < X.size(); i++) {
        double new_val = (double) X[i];
        test.push_back(new_val);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I quite understand what you need. You are doing two things here,

1. dealing with type conversion between integer and floating point types
2. reshaping the arrays between row and column vector

`cv::Mat::reshape` is a little different from numpy's reshape but does the same thing. you could have two Mats sharing the same data, and you use the one for a row view and the other for a column view.

```
cv::Mat m1_column, m2_row;
m2_row = m1_column.reshape(0, 1);
// first arg: number of channels. 0 means same.
// second arg: number of rows. make it a row vector.
```

`cv::Mat::convertTo` is roughly equivalent to numpy's `ndarray.astype`. it copies the values, converted to the desired type, into another `cv::Mat`.

```
cv::Mat m1_floats, m2_ints, m3_floats;
m1_floats.convertTo(m2_ints, CV_8U);
m2_ints.convertTo(m3_floats, CV_32F);
```

combine both as you need.

you don't even need to move between column and row format. just use a single index in `Mat::at<>()`. it'll run through the matrix as if it were flattened.

you can construct a `Mat` from a `std::vector` so it shares the vector's memory:

```
std::vector<int> X; // contains values from somewhere, ints should be 32 bit
cv::Mat X_as_a_Mat(1, X.size(), CV_32S, X.data()); // a single-row Mat sharing the std::vector's data
cv::Mat X_as_doubles;
X_as_a_Mat.convertTo(X_as_doubles, CV_64F); // converts data type
```

this code assumes that `int` is a 32 bit signed type (`CV_32S`). I don't know what element type your `vector<ld>` is supposed to be.

Comment: Thanks so much.  A little confused. Is `m1_column` supposed to be my `M` and `m2_row` supposed to be my `X`?

Comment: Also, I don't understand where my `X` comes into play here. It looks like your suggestion deals only with cv::Mat types and not vectors. I could be understanding wrong...

Comment: ah I see, you need to deal with std::vector. I'll amend the answer.